# preventing a user from changing the password more than once - openldap

Tags: ldap, openldap

Centos 7, openldap 2.4.44 (slapd)

configured the ppolicy password policy. I need to make sure that the user cannot change his password more than 1 time (so that he can change the password only once, after which he would not have such an opportunity). can someone implemented similarly and be able to suggest what attributes / policies I can achieve such a restriction? in the ppolicy documentation, I did not find an attribute / directive suitable for such a case

my case is something like a subscription method:

1. an account is created for the user
2. the pwdMaxAge policy attribute sets the lifetime of the account password (thereby, the account validity period is limited, since in such a case an expired password = non-working account)

   2.1 but the password lifetime limitation in the pwdMaxAge attribute can be bypassed simply by re-creating the password (change), and the pwdMaxAge countdown will start over.
3. After creating the account, the user is sent a password, which he will have to change to his own.

   3.1 to change the password for users, self-service-password (https://github.com/ltb-project/self-service-password) was deployed - where users can change it by entering the password sent to them as "old" and setting a new one your password - at this point the pwdMaxAge password policies are reset, this is normal.

now the problem: the user can even after half a year log into the web form and change his password, thereby resetting the pwdMaxAge countdown and extending the password and account expiration date. Therefore, I want to limit the number of attempts to change the password to one: when the user changes the password sent to him to his own from clause 3.1 and so that after that he cannot change the password again

Comment: Set `pwdAllowUserChange` to false after the first change.

Comment: NB [tag:pwd] does not refer to passwords. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: @user207421 sorry for pwd tag.

Comment: @user207421 the pwdAllowUserChange attribute will have to be set manually by everyone who changes the password. unfortunately this does not solve the automation of the process and does not exclude manual account management ... :(

Comment: Define 'everybody who changes the password'. Surely this means an *application* that you are writing? And if it doesn't, you're off-topic.

Comment: @user207421 sorry, but I do not quite understand what you mean

Comment: If you're writing the app that lets the users change their passwords, put this step into the code. If you're not writing an app you are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to restrict the user from changing the password at once:
*[pwdMinAge](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/PwdChangedTime)* attribute

pwdMinAge=3600
This attribute controls the minimum time (in seconds) between password changes. In the above example, the password can be changed no more than once an hour (3600 seconds). Attempts to change the password before this time has expired will be rejected. The default value is 0, which allows the password to be changed at any time since the last change.

it means that:

- pwdMinAge = 3600
- pwdMaxAge = 3600

and for the entire period (1 hour) the user can change his password only once.